# android espresso Waiting for root hierarchy to have focus, 5th activity

Tags: android, android-espresso

So I'm attempting to write some UI Tests. It is my first time using espresso.

I eventually got to a point where I was comfortable with how everything worked. Then once I tried to test these activities which are 5 levels deep in the hierarchy every single espresso function starts failing. 
It gives the error at the bottom of this question.

I see this reported only a few times on google (including stack overflow) but most of those people were trying to find a toast message. I'm just trying to get any control possible on my activity. using getCurrentActivity I can even get the activity in the foreground. But every time i Try onView(withId(R.id.some_id)).anyfunction it fails after 10 seconds giving the error.

some of the solutions say to use the following code

```
onView(withText("someText")).inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(getCurrentActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

this would presumably search anything other than the activity (meant for toast messages). I tried this without the not() and it still gives me my error after 10 seconds. The error says my root never takes focus, but if this method sets my root as the currentActivity how is that possible?

It seems like this is some kind of espresso glitch where espresso is not able to see any control in an activity 5 levels deep (I started the test in my first activity and the ui test clicked various buttons until it got to this activity 5 levels in). I have three use cases for the beginning of this test, each one ends up launching a different activity at level 5. I'm getting this bug on each of the three activities even though each Activity is different.

```
Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus and not request layout for 10 seconds. If you specified a non default root matcher, it may be picking a root that never takes focus. Root:
Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@b32be4e, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@b32be4e, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string={(0,0)(fillxfill) sim={adjust=resize} ty=BASE_APPLICATION wanim=0x10302fe
  fl=LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR SPLIT_TOUCH HARDWARE_ACCELERATED DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
  pfl= remains{ 0x1000000 } naviIconColor=0}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=2220, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params={(0,0)(fillxfill) sim={adjust=resize} ty=BASE_APPLICATION wanim=0x10302fe
  fl=LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR SPLIT_TOUCH HARDWARE_ACCELERATED DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
  pfl= remains{ 0x1000000 } naviIconColor=0}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}}
```

I'm convinced this is an espresso glitch, but if anyone can tell why it would fail please let me know. (btw, I've tried thread.sleep, it doesn't make a difference).